# java split() remove first word

Tags: java, split

I tried to execute the following code, but I am getting two different responses. Can anyone please explain me what is wrong with the following code. I would like to have my first result like the second one.

```
try
{
    String line ="<acc><add><s>alpha/s><ed>1234567891011</ed></add></acc><acc><add><s>beta</s><ed>1234567891011</ed></add></acc>";
    String eachLine = new String(line);
    if (eachLine.startsWith("<acc>"))
    {
        for (String allLine : eachLine.split("<acc>"))
            System.out.println(allLine);

    }
    String Str = new String("Welcome-to-Tutorialspoint.com");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Return Value :");
    if (Str.startsWith("Welcome"))
    {
        for (String retval : Str.split("-"))
        {
            System.out.println(retval);
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output :

```
<add><s>alpha/s><ed>1234567891011</ed></add></acc>
<add><s>beta</s><ed>1234567891011</ed></add></acc>
```

Return Value:

```
Welcome
to
Tutorialspoint.com
```

Comment: What is the problem here ?
if you mean that `<acc>` disappeared then yeah of course it does as it is your split char --> you just have to add it again after in this case

Comment: You want `<acc><add><s>alpha/s><ed>1234567891011</ed></add></acc>` instead of `<add><s>alpha/s><ed>1234567891011</ed></add></acc>` ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're attempting to achieve here, you need to be clearer :S

Comment: Thanks for the code edit. I would like to know why outputs are different

Comment: You question is unclear. What do you mean why the two outputs are different? What is the expected output?

Comment: This is my expected output without using appending "<acc>" to allLine .   <acc><add><s>alpha/s><ed>1234567891011</ed></add></acc>
<acc><add><s>beta</s><ed>1234567891011</ed></add></acc>

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = "<acc><add><s>alpha/s><ed>1234567891011</ed></add></acc><acc>   <add><s>beta</s><ed>1234567891011</ed></add></acc>";
List<Integer> inbdexArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int index = line.indexOf("<acc>");
         index >= 0;
         index = line.indexOf("<acc>", index + 1))
    {
     inbdexArray.add(index);
    }

 System.out.println(line.substring(inbdexArray.get(0), inbdexArray.get(1)));
```

Does it help?

Comment: Not really, I want the output which I mentioned earlier. I wanted to use split method and each time when I encounter <acc> in a string I want it to printed in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by replacing

```
System.out.println(retval);
```

with

```
System.out.println("<acc>" + retval);
```

if you are sure you have an `</acc>` in each case as the outermost tag. Your `<acc>` disappeared, because it was used as separator for `split`.

Comment: Oh I got it. "-" is consumed and it is printed. I'm so stupid that I didn't realize it. Thanks for your time guys !!!

Comment: No problem, it happens. If my answer was helpful, you might consider accepting it.